# Locally weighted smoothing for binary valued random variable

Tags: numpy, scipy, histogram, logistic-regression, probability-density

I have a random variable as follows:

f(x) = 1 with probability g(x)

f(x) = 0 with probability 1-g(x)

where 0 < g(x) < 1.

Assume g(x) = x. Let's say I am observing this variable without knowing the function g and obtained 100 samples as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import binned_statistic

list = np.ndarray(shape=(200,2))

g = np.random.rand(200)
for i in range(len(g)):
    list[i] = (g[i], np.random.choice([0, 1], p=[1-g[i], g[i]]))

print(list)
plt.plot(list[:,0], list[:,1], 'o')
```

[Plot of 0s and 1s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8CWp.png)

Now, I would like to retrieve the function g from these points. The best I could think is to use draw a histogram and use the mean statistic:

```
bin_means, bin_edges, bin_number = binned_statistic(list[:,0], list[:,1], statistic='mean', bins=10)
plt.hlines(bin_means, bin_edges[:-1], bin_edges[1:], lw=2)
```

[Histogram mean statistics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uyypd.png)

Instead, I would like to have a continuous estimation of the generating function.

I guess it is about kernel density estimation but I could not find the appropriate pointer.

Comment: you can find kdes in `Statsmodels` `sklearn` and `scipy` has one too. If you want just a plot look at `seaborn` and it's `distplot` or `kdeplot`.  But  why do you want a kde for binary data?

Comment: @MarvinTaschenberger It is possible that my remarks about kde may be misleading. It seems that I have a logistic regression problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression#Example:_Probability_of_passing_an_exam_versus_hours_of_study. But I am not trying to fit a model. I want to plot it in a smooth fashion.

Comment: This also looks relevant: http://thestatsgeek.com/2014/09/13/checking-functional-form-in-logistic-regression-using-loess/

Answer (score 1):

straightforward without explicitly fitting an estimator:

```
import seaborn as sns 
g = sns.lmplot(x= , y= , y_jitter=.02 , logistic=True)
```

plug in `x=` your exogenous variable and  analogously `y =` dependent variable. `y_jitter` is jitter the point for better visibility if you have a lot of data points. `logistic = True` is the main point here. It will give you the logistic regression line of the data.

Seaborn is basically tailored around `matplotlib` and works great with `pandas`, in case you want to extend your data to a DataFrame.

Comment: Now, I understand that what I was looking for is Locally Weighted Scatterplot Smoothing. Thank you pointing sns. 
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['x'] = list[:,0]
df['y'] = list[:,1]
sns.lmplot(x='x', y='y', data = df, lowess=True)
plt.show()